# Are There any Web-Based Load-Balancing Managers?

Tags: monitoring, load-balancing, network-monitoring, web-applications, mysql-cluster

I've setup load-balancing and clustering on a few linux systems for serving web and database content, and each time it's a fairly laborious process.

So I'm wondering, are there any web-based managers, or possibly just monitoring interfaces, for load-balancing of this sort? I've searched around a bit, but haven't come up with anything substantial.

Comment: "Web-based managers" are somewhat antithetical to the goal of reducing labour.

Comment: Depending on the utility, obviously. If the utility were more easily configured and allowed for increased ease-of-management over traditional methods for maintaining the system, then it's inherently worthwhile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is HaProxy, an opensource software providing load balancing and proxying for TCP and HTTP-based applications by spreading requests across multiple servers.

It has a web interface for monitoring and get statistics about the balanced services. Here there is demo of the web interface http://demo.haproxy.org/

Comment: Definitely a decent load balancing utility and monitoring suite. If only they included web-based management systems. I'll go ahead and set this as best answer, as my thread has apparently been labeled as "off-topic".